# Do people only post new questions when they are sat at their desk working?

Tags: discussion

Do we get more site visitors M-F than at the weekend?

Is this because we are only getting 'overflow' visitors that happen to be working at the time? If this is the case we seriously need to 'embrace and extend' new audiences!

Comment: Do experts come to Bicycles.SE to get answers to their questions?

Comment: And do the experts stay to give their answers ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is a huge overlap between all sites and M-F work hours. So yes, the reality is, people participate on the internet at their job. Whether this should happen or not is not for me to decide..

Only a handful of sites (Super User is a notable exception) do not have a *huge* dip in traffic on weekends.

Answer (score 1):

I usually check the site on my lunch break, any other breaks, and then at home again in the evening.  It's really easy for people to pop over to the site while they are working so I think that traffic pattern is common.

Our bicycles.se traffic is hovering around 3000-4000 page views a day on weekdays, and falls to 2000 every weekend.

Recently we have been getting 20% of our visits from referring sites (StackOverflow being the largest by far), 73% from search engines (google dominating) and the rest from direct links.

I do think that most of our members came from other SE sites, so ideas about how to reach out to new blood are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the stats. Seems we have a long way to go, but I am glad to see that Google results are higher than 'referring SE sites'.